# What’s the minimum mass required for a star to burn helium?

Tags: stars, fusion

What’s the minimum mass required for a star to burn helium? I’ve liked online but I’ve gotten inconsistent answers.

Comment: What answers did you find? https://www.atnf.csiro.au/outreach/education/senior/astrophysics/stellarevolution_postmain.html gives a minimum of $0.5M_\odot$, but I expect that the exact cutoff depends on metallicity.

Comment: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Astronomy__Cosmology/Astronomy_1e_(OpenStax)/22%3A_Stars_from_Adolescence_to_Old_Age/22.04%3A_Further_Evolution_of_Stars "When the triple-alpha process begins in low-mass (about 0.8 to 2.0 solar masses) stars" https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/25289917.pdf "For stars with masses more than ∼0.9 solar mass (M⊙) the temperatures in the center can reach the burning temperature of He,"

Answer (score 0):

about half a solar mass. Lower than that, and helium in the core will not ignite.